# MCR is not working on windows 7 professional

Tags: matlab

I have compiled and standalone application using MATLAB (32-bit windows 7 ultimate).

even though I have installed MCR of required version on target PC (32-bit windows 7 professional) my application is not working. (installation path C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime)

Note: on other windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit system my application is working fine

Comment: environment variable "path" is also set as required

Comment: any error message?  (run exe from dos prompt)

Comment: could not find version 7.15 of MCR. Attempting to load mclmcrrt7_15.dll

Comment: correct version is already installed and system 'path' variable is also set...

Answer (score 0):

That message is indicating that it cannot find the path - I know you said that the path is set correctly.

However I would try setting the PATH variable manually in a dos prompt and then run the exe and see if it will launch.

Comment: Can you manually find the files?  Also try reinstalling the MCR

Comment: I figured it out. actually antivirus is enabled and that was causing problem.